# AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'heatmap'

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I am fairly new to Python. I am trying to run the below code and getting Module not found error. I tried checking seaborn version and it was the latest. After multiple tries I placed my file in a different path and it started working fine. Could someone help me understand this behavior.

My Anaconda path:  C:\Users\Kumar>
Placed the file in same path and it did not run.

Placed the file in Downloads and ran again from Jupyter and it worked fine. Please help in understanding what is the difference and how can I resolve these errors in future

My Code:

```
corr = df.corr() 
plt.figure(figsize=(14,14))
plt.figure(figsize=(14,14))
sns.heatmap(corr,cmap= 'coolwarm')

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-522f105baca0> in <module>
      2 plt.figure(figsize=(14,14))
      3 plt.figure(figsize=(14,14))
----> 4 sns.heatmap(corr,cmap= 'coolwarm')

AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'heatmap'
```

Comment: Maybe you created a file with the name `seaborn.py`?

Comment: You are a lifesaver bro.. I didn't even think of that... I had created it at the very beginning almost 2 months back when I started and completely forgot about it. Lesson learnt

Answer (score 0):

possibly you need to install additional modules:

- statsmodels
- fastcluster

It works for me

see https://seaborn.pydata.org/installing.html